# TextBox change date Format when insert into sql

Tags: c#

I want to change date Format when I insert my textbox into sql.
I'm try something like this:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into memberinfo date='"
        + textBox1.ToString("d/M/yyyy") + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But i get error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Dates in c# code or in Sql Server database have no format. They are just dates (and time sometime) a bunch of bits that represent a datetime value. It is how the program (or a database program like sql server management studio) that show these dates that applies a format for the humans to understand. Is your column _date_ a datetime type column?

Comment: I think something is going on with globalization settings. Example if my textbox have this Format MM/dd/yyyy In my sql database i will have this result dd/MM/yyyy. Or is there any way when i press save button to change it from dd/MM/yyyy To MM/dd/yyyy??

Comment: Do not store strings as dates in a database column. Use a date type column. How do you plan to execute searches over a column of type string that represent dates? They never work,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to save a date as string you can use this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text).ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

But it is dangerous because you assume the entered date is in a correct format.
Better use a `DatePicker` control and store it in a column of SqlType `Date`

Also your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Better use **parameterized queries** instead of composing the SQL string manually

Answer (score 0):

In order to use SQL you dont need foramt, Only corecct DateTime object.

You Can cast stringto date:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```